# pdo php addison with stored variables from same field

Tags: php, mysql, database, math, pdo

Adding togeather all ratings from my results.

Ok I have a table called ratings and in the table it is layed out like this.

```
     ID | UserID | Rating | TMDB |  TYPE
     -----------------------------------
     1      34        6     432      3
     -----------------------------------
     2      34        9     432      3
```

My sql is

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `tbl_rating` WHERE `tmdb`='" . $tmdb . "' AND `type`='" . $type . "' ";
```

ok this pulls up the information I want. I can now use a while or foreach command to call $row['rating']. However I dont know how I can add the results togeather or do any basic math. This is a movie rating database and I am trying to get my script to add togeather all the "ratings" in the results column and then work out the average vote.

I hope this make scence. Any help would be great thank you all!

this script has star rating for Gore, Scare, Acting, Story (this is the where I use the type field).

Comment: What problem are you having? Just using standard math operators like `+` and `/`. `$total_rating = $total_rating + $row['rating']`.

Comment: You can also use MySQL aggregation functions like `SUM()` and `AVG()`, instead of doing it in your script.

Comment: I cant use $row['rating']+$row['rating'] its the same field and the only way I could think is $row[1]['rating']+$row[2]['rating'] but there must be a better way? i suppose a counter might work in the $row[$counter][rating]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to a variable containing the total.

```
$total_rating = 0;
$rating_count = 0;
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    $total_rating += $row['rating'];
    $rating_count++;
}
if ($rating_count > 0) {
    $avg_rating = $total_rating / $rating_count;
} else {
    $avg_rating = 0;
}
```

You could also just do this in the query:

```
$sql = "SELECT AVG(rating) AS avg_rating FROM `tbl_rating` WHERE `tmdb`= :tmdb AND `type`= :type ";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':tmdb', $tmdb);
$stmt->bindParam(':type', $type);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$avg_rating = $row['avg_rating'];
```

Comment: thanks once again A++++ :)

Comment: I feel really silly writing an answer like this, it's Computer Programming 101.

Comment: I know sometime I struggle on the easier stuff. I learn as I go along... now i just need to figure out how to show the top 5 gorey films (type:2) lol